# CentOS7 再起動したら、/var/run/ 直下に作成したディレクトリが削除されたのですが、内容確認する方法はありますか？

Tags: centos

CentOS7 再起動したら、/var/run/ 直下に作成したディレクトリが削除されたのですが、内容確認するために復活させる方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOSで`/var/run`の下が消えるのは仕様です。

参考：
[お前らもさっさとハマって泣くべきCentOS7の落とし穴4つ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/suemoc/items/e29285e8e67263298f35)

> CentOS7では、/runディレクトリがtmpfsファイルシステムでマウントされています。
>   つまり、 OSを再起動すると/run (=/var/run)に置かれたファイルは全て削除されてしまいます。

`tmpfs`とは物理メモリで、ファイルシステムとしてマウントすればHDD等より高速にアクセスできる反面、再起動時には基本的にデータは削除されます。

削除されたファイルのあったファイルシステムが何なのか分かりませんが、例えば`ext3/ext4`であれば [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) という復元を試みることができるソフトウェアがあります。